# How does fwrite() work

Tags: c

I have to use fwrite() instead of fputc(), but I can't understand how it works.
I have tried to use it but it writes in binary. This is the code:

```
while ((c = fgetc(f1)) != EOF) 
{  
    if (fwrite(&f3, sizeof(f3), 1, f3) == EOF) 
    {
        printf("valore iniziale di errno = %d\n",errno);
        perror("errore:");
        exit(1);        
    }
}
```

f1 is the file where some text is written and f3 is the file where I want to write the content of f1 but I see only binary text.

Comment: If you want a string representation of something written you have to first represent it in a string, then write it. `snprintf()` is your friend.

Comment: You probably have, or can find, the source code for `fwrite`. If you mean you don't understand how fwrite usage works, there are plenty of online tutorials for that.

Comment: @Rob i know but i can't understand the parameters that fwrite require. So i don't know if the parameters that i have put are right or not

Comment: It is really basic knowledge. The C tag wiki points to a [list of books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) among which [The C Book](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/) that contains a chapter about formatted (printf) and unformatted (fwrite) IO. It is available on line so you should read it. Feel free to come back here to ask more precise questions.

Comment: You tried using it but it writes in binary?  From the man page for `fwrite`:  "fread, fwrite - **binary** stream input/output".  The documentation is your friend.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to read the contents of one file and write it to another just with a single `fwrite`. That won't work. `fwrite` can't copy the contents of a file by referencing the file pointer from `fwrite`. You need to read the manual page for `fwrite` carefully. It will write out the contents of a data buffer. A file stream pointer is NOT a data buffer pointer containing file contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## How `fwrite` "works"

---

You can start by looking at the [`fwrite` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite). It's signature is:

```
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

So, let's break down each argument:

1. `ptr` is the source location of your data (where you data is).
2. `size` is the size of each element of data. `fwrite` writes in chunks of `size` bytes each time it loops.
3. `nmemb` is the number of loops `fwrite` will perform.
4. `stream` is the file descriptor (`FILE*`) of your output file.

So, with that in mind, imagine this:

```
// our dear string
char *str = "#SO";

// open a bogus file to write
FILE *fp = fopen(foo, "wb");

// call fwrite and store returned value
size_t ret = fwrite(str, 3, 1, fp);
```

This code will do the following (*other than not compiling*): Starting at location pointed by `str`, it will write `3` bytes in the file pointed by `fp` `1` time. However, if you did it like this:

```
size_t ret = fwrite(str, 1, 3, fp);
```

That would tell `fwrite` to write `1` byte to the file for every iteration it does, and it would do `3` iterations.

In your case, you read a character from `f1` and want to write it to `f3`. Therefore, you should have something like this:

```
ret = fwrite(&c, sizeof(c), 1, f3);
```

That will read the binary character from `f1` and copy it to `f3`.

**Note that this might not be (and probably is not) the way `fwrite` works internally. What I presented here is the mental model I use to remember its arguments. If you actually read `fwrite` source code, you may find a very different implementation.**

## Example

---

So, a simple program to copy from `f1` to `f2` is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c;
    FILE *f1 = fopen("foo.txt", "rb");
    FILE *f2 = fopen("bar.txt", "wb");
    size_t ret;

    while((ret = fread(&c, sizeof(c), 1, f1))) 
        ret = fwrite(&c, sizeof(c), 1, f2);


    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might note that `fwrite()` will not return EOF under most practical circumstances.  To return EOF, you'd have to attempt to write an enormous amount of data — `(size_t)-1` bytes worth — and it would have to succeed.